# Instance Method createARGBBitmapContextFromImage not found. Trying to get a pixel of an image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pixel, cgcontext

I am trying a few approaches to get pixel color or alpha of an image. So far every attempt has brought me long time process.

For now, I am trying the following method, but I can't go through as xcode is telling me that `Ïnstance Method createARGBBitmapContextFromImage not found` when trying to get context `(CGContextRef cgctx )`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
- (BOOL) isWallPixel:(CGPoint)point
{

BOOL result = FALSE;
UIColor* color = nil;

CGImageRef inImage;

UIImage* imagem = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];

inImage = imagem.CGImage;


// Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};


// Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
// allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
// raw image data in the specified color space.
CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage);

// Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
// context.
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL) {
    //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
    //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
    int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
    int alpha =  data[offset];
    int red = data[offset+1];
    int green = data[offset+2];
    int blue = data[offset+3];
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
}

// When finished, release the context
//CGContextRelease(cgctx);
// Free image data memory for the context
if (data) { free(data); }
if(alpha==0)
  result = TRUE;

return result;
}
```

Comment: Is that method present in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you're looking for, [which I found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394450/rgb-in-image-processing-in-iphone-app).  You need to add this to your .m file and also add the method declaration to your .h file.

```
- (CGContextRef)createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef)inImage
{
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *bitmapData;
    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc(bitmapByteCount);
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData,
                                    pixelsWide,
                                    pixelsHigh,
                                    8,   // bits per component
                                    bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free(bitmapData);
        fprintf(stderr,"Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return context;
}
```

Comment: It is working now... but this approach is still too slow for my app. For every move of the user's touch, it checks the next position pixel information. It is far from being smooth.. :(